# deleting old image record while updating paperclip polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-plugins, polymorphism

I am using paperclip polymorphic plugins to manage attachments. I have a problem now that I cannot delete the old attachments while updating. Is there a way to achieve this or any way round to that I always gets the recent attachment.